# How to simulate a corrupt state exception in .NET 4?

Tags: .net, state, simulation, corrupt

Well, in .NET 4 Microsoft added the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute:

[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute.aspx)

I want to test this feature. How can I bring my application to a "corrupt state"?

Comment: Lets say you catch it.  What are you going to do with it?

Comment: Log it. We have a production crash with no logs whatsoever. This new log will help us.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Screwing up the garbage collected heap is always a good way:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


class Program {
  unsafe static void Main(string[] args) {
    var obj = new byte[1];
    var pin = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    byte* p = (byte*)pin.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    for (int ix = 0; ix < 256; ++ix) *p-- = 0;
    GC.Collect();   // kaboom
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Just dereference a random number:

```
    private static unsafe void AccessViolation()
    {
        byte b = *(byte*) (8762765876);
    }
```

or overflow the stack:

```
    private static void StackOverflow()
    {
        StackOverflow();
    }
```

Comment: According to Microsoft, StackOverflowException is not a CSE (Corrupted State Exception) and cannot be caught as one: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/All-about-Corrupted-State-Exceptions-in-NET4.aspx#s4-corrupted-state-exceptions-cses-in-net4

Answer (score 0):

Test `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` feature:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...

[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
public void HandleCorruptedStateException()
{
    try
    {
        var ptr = new IntPtr(42);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(42, ptr, true);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```