# How do I trash the GC heap in Mono?

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to (on purpose) trash the GC heap in Mono, hoping to cause an `ExecutionEngineException` or a core dump. How can I do this in C#? I don't want to call Marshel or the like.

EDIT: I am perfectly willing to use unsafe code. I have caused a crash but it has always been a NullReferenceException or a StackOverflowException. I want something that safe code could not do.

Comment: Unless there is a specific bug in your version of Mono related to the GC that allows for this, you cannot do it from within C#.

Comment: Being able to do this from regular C# would be a huge bug in Mono

Comment: Not if the code is unsafe.

Comment: ... Why do you want to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate a corrupt state exception in .NET 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950130/how-to-simulate-a-corrupt-state-exception-in-net-4)