# Cannot catch a corrupted state exception

Tags: c#, corrupted-state-exception

I get a corrupted state exception (CSE) in my application using the framework .NET 4.5.1. This exception taken from the event viewer is:

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEEB8F75CB (000007FEEB7B0000) with exit code 80131506.

I get the same exception into the event viewer by using the following code from the issue [How to simulate a corrupt state exception in .NET 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950130/how-to-simulate-a-corrupt-state-exception-in-net-4):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program {
  unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new byte[1];
        var pin = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        byte* p = (byte*)pin.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        for (int ix = 0; ix < 256; ++ix) *p-- = 0;
        GC.Collect();   // kaboom
    }
}
```

I use the attributes HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions and SecurityCritical on the handler of event UnhandledException as discussed in the haindl's response for the issue [Gracefully handling corrupted state exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956163/gracefully-handling-corrupted-state-exceptions).

But I cannot catch this error with it. Why ?

That works with a access violation generated with:

```
private static unsafe void AccessViolation()
{
    byte b = *(byte*) (8762765876);
}
```

The code of the handler where I log the error message is executed but of course, I don't get the same error as in my application.

UPDATE:

I attempt to catch the CSE by reproducing the 3 steps described in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception):

1. Recompile as a .NET 3.5 assembly and run it in .NET 4.0.
2. Add a line to your application's config file under the configuration/runtime element:
3. Decorate the methods you want to catch these exceptions in with the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute. See
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#id0070035 for
   details.

But that does not work for me !

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
        [SecurityCritical]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    PerformException();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                }
            }
        }

        [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
        [SecurityCritical]
        unsafe static void PerformException()
        {
            var obj = new byte[1];
            var pin = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            byte* p = (byte*)pin.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            for (int ix = 0; ix < 256; ++ix) *p-- = 0;
            GC.Collect(); // CSE occurs here.
        }
    }
}
```

My app.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Why is the CSE not caught ?

Note I must allow the code to build with the unsafe mode because it is required by the following line code:

> byte* p = (byte*)pin.AddrOfPinnedObject();

I repeat it's only for debugging. The goal is to find the code part which occurs this error type in a greater application in order to bring a fix.

Comment: As this articel says (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603994.aspx) you shouldn't handle CorruptedStateExceptions, since you can't ensure that your catch block is unaffected by any sideeffect, which may be the cause why you aren't able to catch it.

Comment: My handler contains only a error log. How to find what is the problem in my code ? That's a big application using threading, ... I just want to localize the part of not working code. So, that's just for debugging.

Comment: Certain internal errors in the runtime cannot be caught by any means, because they immediately disable the CLR, preventing any further managed code from executing. Use [procdump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) to capture a dump of the application as it encounters the unhandled exception, then load that up in Visual Studio (or windbg, for more thorough analysis). This is tons more reliable than any last-minute exception handler, especially if actual internal corruption of data is involved (which an in-process exception handler couldn't accurately log).

Comment: It is simply not a CSE, ExecutionEngineException is far too nasty to consider managed code able to handle it.  Corruption of the GC heap is the usual underlying problem, you can't reliably execute any managed code with the heap shot to smithereens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gracefully handling corrupted state exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956163/gracefully-handling-corrupted-state-exceptions)